# Increase the speed of this code? Foreach

Tags: php, foreach

```
$pass = array();

foreach ($var as $index) 
{
    if($index['Data']['Show'] == false)
        continue;

    $pass[] = $index;
}

echo json_encode($pass);
```

I need to know how to get the same result in a more streamlined and faster.

Comment: Use `array_filter`

Comment: How much data do you have that a foreach with a 3 lines of code is not fast enough? I doubt there would be a solution that would speed it up more than this, even array_filter (while it would be faster, it wouldn't be like 100x or anything significant). Perhaps use a database and query for only rows you want to show.

Comment: How do you know this code is slow? How much data do you try to process?

Comment: It is for a dynamic array that will get data from a navigation bar editable from MySQL, for some reason Jquery sometimes takes longer than 200 ms to obtain the information, and i suposse this solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be slightly faster, I haven't tested, but if `['Data']['Show']` will be `true` or `false` then this is how I would do it:

```
$pass = array_filter($var, function($v) { return $v['Data']['Show']; });
```

If it could be other values that evaluate to `false` then:

```
$pass = array_filter($var, function($v) { return $v['Data']['Show'] !== false; });
```